# jQuery Custom Data Attribute with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am using [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/#cta) and right now I have a CSS style for **animated2500** which means it will take 2.5 seconds to animate.  The style is:

```
.animated2500 {
    -webkit-animation: 2500ms ease;
    -moz-animation: 2500ms ease;
    -ms-animation: 2500ms ease;
    animation: 2500ms ease;
}
```

So in my HTML I would do:

```
<p class="animated2500 pulse">Takes 2.5 seconds to pulse</p>
```

There has to be an easier way to do this though, because I will want to specify how many seconds without creating a custom class for it each time.

Is there a way to use a custom data attribute like:  `<p data-delay="5000" class="fade">Fade in 5 econds</p>` would that work?

How could I accomplish something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? Or even JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know I thought you could only grab the value of the data value through javascript and then somehow create a class for the CSS or something.  Not sure how this will work.

Comment: Yeah, as @T.J.Crowder said, this doesn't use any JS. BUT, you could easily do this using JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use pure CSS for this, individual styles are the way to go.

If you really want to use a `data-*` attribute, since you've tagged your question `jquery`, I'll post a jQuery-specific answer although CSS animations and data attributes are not specific to jQuery (or even JavaScript):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".pulse[data-delay]").each(function() {
        var value = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-delay"), 10);
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            value = value + "ms ease";
            this.style["-webkit-animation"] = value;
            this.style["-moz-animation"] = value;
            this.style["-ms-animation"] = value;
            this.style["animation"] = value;
        }
    });
});
```

That runs through the elements on DOM ready and applies the style directly. I don't like it for several reasons (not least that new elements added to the page post-load won't get handled), but if you really, really don't want to create specific classes...

Comment: I am open to suggestions.  I just figured it would be a jquery solution, it doesn't have to be. But you are suggesting just creating a bunch of classes for each time I need?

Comment: his code appears to suggest you give all the links the same class. in his example he is using the class `pulse`. then set the time in ms in the `data-type` attribute (just as you proposed).

Comment: @Drew: I'd be a bit worried if you need a huge number of classes, because that would make me wonder if the page would be too busy for most people. :-) But that would be the pure CSS way, which has advantages. If you want the `data-delay` attribute feature, though, the above should do it. You could split out the function so you could reuse it on elements you added later.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this will work? (untested)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p[data-delay]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('-webkit-animation',$(this).attr('data-delay')+'ms ease');
        $(this).css('-moz-animation',$(this).attr('data-delay')+'ms ease');
        $(this).css('-ms-animation',$(this).attr('data-delay')+'ms ease');
        $(this).css('animation',$(this).attr('data-delay')+'ms ease');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: **Every single time** you call `$()`, you're actually issuing a couple of function calls and a memory allocation. Can I respectfully suggest you do it *once* rather than eight times?

Comment: tbh, after i posted it, i thought of declaring the data-type as a variable. but i had already seen your answer as being better than mine, so i left it alone. that and the fact that i never knew the existence of `this.style` i always used jquery `.css`. but i will be using what i learned from your answer in the future!

Comment: `@Johnny`: LOL. jQuery's `css` does a lot to smooth over browser differences, so don't abandon it completely. :-) But in this case I didn't think I needed it. If I had, though, I'd've just starting with `var $this = $(this)` and then reused the `$this` everywhere I need the jQuery instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p[data-delay]").each(function(){
        this.style.webkitAnimationDuration = $(this).attr('data-delay') + 's';
    );
});
```